# Is this possible using ant?

Tags: ant

I have a requirement where in i have to create a file, which will contain the source directory name, target directory name where it would be deployed, and list of file (.jars) that i need to deploy.

I was thinking of having a properties file where i would specify multiple lines of following type

```
[Src dirctory name] [destination directory]
```

Then i would read each line from above file and list all the files in [src directory name] and would like to have following in my final properties file.

```
appversion @appversion@ (value would com using ant filters)

[some static stuff]

SrcDir [absolute path of Src directory1]  
DestDir [destination directory as is]  
file 555 [file1.jar]  
file 555 [file2.jar]  
SrcDir [absolute path of Src directory2]  
DestDir [destination directory as is]  
file 555 [file1.jar]  
file 555 [file2.jar]  
.  
.  
.  
SrcDir [absolute path of Src directory n]  
DestDir [destination directory as is]  
file 555 [file1.jar]  
file 555 [file2.jar]
```

Can i do something like

```
appversion @appversion@ (value would com using ant filters)

[some static stuff]

@finallist@
```

where final list would be generated as above? or is there a better way of doing the same. I know we can do it using script but just wanted to know if we can do it easily using ant?

Can you please help me? I was thinking of using ant filters but an not able to create the structure of above type. Can you please help me?

Thanks,
Almas

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a series of the [echo task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) to append text to the end of the file.

```
<echo message="${text.to.append}" file="${prop.file}" append="true"/>
```

or

```
<echo file="${prop.file}" append="true">
multiple lines of text to append to file here
....
</echo>
```